# LNK 2019 error on missing library in W5.cpp

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to run my code of getting a grade num to changing it to a char but I keep getting the LNK 2019 error even though I think I'm not missing anything any #includes I still don't know what is wrong will post my code and the error since I can't seem to find the problem any help would be great thanks. This is the main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include "Grades.h"
#include "Letter.h"
using namespace sict;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

std::ofstream ofs("Lab5Output.txt");

std::cout << "Command Line : ";
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    std::cout << argv[i] << ' ';
}
std::cout << std::endl;

if (argc == 1) {
    std::cerr << "\n*** Insufficient number of arguments ***\n";
    std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " fileName \n";
    return 1;
}
else if (argc != 2) {
    std::cerr << "\n*** Too many arguments ***\n";
    std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " fileName \n";
    return 2;
}
try
{
    sict::Grades grades(argv[1]);
    auto letter = [](double grade)
    {
        int grd;
        if ((grade >= 90) && (grade <= 100)) {
            grd = Aplus;
        }
        else if ((grade >= 80) && (grade < 90)) { 
            grd = A;
        }
        else if ((grade >= 75) && (grade < 80)) { 
            grd = Bplus;
        }
        else if ((grade >= 70) && (grade < 75)) { 
            grd = B;
        }
        else if ((grade >= 65) && (grade < 70)) { 
            grd = Cplus;
        }
        else if ((grade >= 60) && (grade < 65)) { 
            grd = C;
        }
        else if ((grade >= 55) && (grade < 60)) { 
            grd = Dplus;
        }
        else if ((grade >= 50) && (grade < 55)) { 
            grd = D;
        }
        else {
            grd = F;
        }

        return grd;
    };
    grades.displayGrades(std::cout, letter);
}
catch (const char * err)
{
    throw err;
    return 1;
}
return 0;
ofs.close();
}
```

this is the grades.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "Letter.h"
#include "Grades.h"
using namespace std;
namespace sict {
 Grades::Grades(const char* data ) {
     if (data != nullptr && data[0] != '\0')    {
         int i = 0;
         int j = 0;
         int sn;
         double grade;
         string getMarks;
         ifstream fs(data);
         while (getline(fs, getMarks)) {
             i++;
         }
         lines = i;
         this->studentnum = new int[lines];
         this->gradenum = new double[lines];
         fs.close();
         fs.open(data);
         while (getline(fs, getMarks)){
             while (fs >> sn >> grade)
             {
                 this->studentnum[i] = sn;
                 this->gradenum[i] = grade;
                 i++;
             }
         }
     }
 }
 template <typename T>
 void Grades::displayGrades(std::ostream& os, T letter) const {
     for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
         int grade = lambda(gradenum);
         string letter = convert(grade);
         os << studentnum[i] << " " <<gradesnum[i] << " " << letter(gradenum[i])<< std::endl;
     }
 }
}
```

this the grade.h

```
#ifndef SICT_GRADES_H
#define SICT_GRADES_H
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "Letter.h"
namespace sict {
class Grades {
    int* studentnum;
    double* gradenum;
    char gradeletter;
    size_t lines;
public:
    Grades(const Grades&) = delete; 
    Grades(Grades&&) = delete; 
    Grades& operator=(const Grades&) = delete; 
    Grades&& operator=(Grades&&) = delete;
    Grades(const char*);
    template <typename T>
    void displayGrades(std::ostream&, T) const;
    ~Grades() { delete [] studentnum; delete [] gradenum; };
};
}
#endif // !SICT_GRADES_H
```

and this it the letter.h

```
#ifndef SICT_LETTER_H
#define SICT_LETTER_H
#include <string>
#include "Grades.h"
using namespace std;
namespace sict {
enum marks  {
    F, D, Dplus, C, Cplus, B, Bplus, A, Aplus
};
template <typename T>
string convert(T& mark) {
    string grade = "";
    if (mark = marks::F){
        grade = "F";
    }
    else if (mark = marks::D) {
        grade = "D";
    }
    else if (mark = marks::Dplus) {
        grade = "D+";
    }
    else if (mark = marks::C) {
        grade = "C";
    }
    else if (mark = marks::Cplus) {
        grade = "C+";
    }
    else if (mark = marks::B) {
        grade = "B";
    }
    else if (mark = marks::Bplus) {
        grade = "B+";
    }
    else if (mark = marks::A) {
        grade = "A";
    }
    else if (mark = marks::Aplus) {
        grade = "A+";
    }
    return grade;
}
}
#endif // !SICT_GRADES_H
```

but I keep getting this error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall 
sict::Grades::displayGrades<class <lambda_6686105985789fb8252d1ceed5cbf23c> 
>(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class 
<lambda_6686105985789fb8252d1ceed5cbf23c>)const " (?? $displayGrades@V<lambda_6686105985789fb8252d1ceed5cbf23c>@@@Grades@sict@@QBEXAA V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@V<lambda_6686105985789fb8252d1ceed5cbf23c>@@@Z) 
referenced in function _main    Lambda Experssion C:\Users\Albert\Documents\Lambda Experssion\W5.obj    1
```

any help would be greatly appreciated thank you

Comment: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](//stackoverflow.com/q/495021)

Comment: The declaration in your class `void displayGrades(std::ostream&, T) const;` does not match your definition in grade.cpp `void Grades::displayGrades(std::ostream& os, T letter) const`

Comment: @Yastanub 1) What part of it doesn't match? 2) If it didn't match, you would get the error similar to "_definition of 'method' does not match any declaration in 'class'_" before linker would even be invoked.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius a sry i see now i looked too quick.